# Why isn't my span being displayed? Simple password matching

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a simple HTML form for users to enter username and passwords and I'm validating that the passwords match using JavaScript. However for some reason I can't get the span to display whether or not the passwords match.

```
window.onload = init;

function init(){

function passMatch(){
    console.log("Matching words.");
    var pwd1 = document.getElementById("pwd1").value;
    var pwd2 = document.getElementById("pwd2").value;
    var output1 = document.getElementById("pwd1Hint");
    var output2 = document.getElementById("pwd2Hint");

if (pwd1 === pwd2){
    output1.innerHTML = "Yes!";
    console.log(output1.textContent);
} else {
    output1.innerHTML = "No!";
    console.log(output1.textContent);
}
}
// event handlers
document.getElementById("pwd1").onchange = passMatch;
document.getElementById("pwd2").onchange = passMatch;
}
```

And here is the relevant HTML...

```
<fieldset name="LoginInfo"><input size="30" placeholder="username"
        name="username" id="username" type="text"> <br>
      <br>
      Password:<br>
      <input size="30" required="required" placeholder="password" name="pwd1"
        id="pwd1" type="password"> <span class="hint" id="pwd1Hint">Password
        is too short (must be at least 8 characters)</span> <br>
      Repeat Password:<br>
      <input size="30" required="required" placeholder="password" name="pwd2"
        id="pwd2" type="password"> <span class="hint" id="pwd2Hint">Passwords
        don't match</span><br>
```

Comment: when is `init` called?

Comment: @DanielA.White first line?

Comment: It's not obvious why it should be not displayed at first place: it's a regular span that will be visible on page load (since it's not hidden)

Comment: I can make your code display "Yes!" and "No!", what's the problem exactly?

Comment: @Drakes I can't get the span to display "Yes!" and "No!" on the page. I can't even get the span to display its default text of "Password is too short (must be at least 8 characters)" when the page loads

Comment: @vikram I took your HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/06udeg4a/ and it shows them by default. Why do you think it should be hidden?

Comment: Agreed. http://jsbin.com/losase/1/

Comment: @vikram, do these fiddle and paste codes work?

Comment: That's weird, on the fiddle it displays properly, but when I test in my browser it doesn't display. Latest version of Firefox.

Comment: There may be other code that we are not seeing that is interfering. Can you post your whole HTML?

Comment: What do you mean "in my browser"? jsiddle is not a browser and it does run in your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to stab at this with limited information, but you said something very interesting to me:

> I can't even get the span to display its default text of "Password is
>   too short (must be at least 8 characters)" when the page loads

But our Fiddle's are working for you. This is static text independent of JavaScript. That tells me that you might have CSS that we are not seeing which is hiding your `span`.

Comment: Our pleasure. Best of luck

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that your init function is never being called. Try just calling that function below the definition - so just define it and then below it add `init()`. That works in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/awt3dxdj/

Then you can just make it an anonymous function that is executed immediately (IIFE).